# Using Streams in C# for SSH library

Tags: c#, stream, ssh.net

I'm working on a Putty-like user-interactive SSH UI using C# and SSH.NET, an open-source library for making SSH connections.  The issue I've been having is that the way all the examples I've been able to find work, they appear to create a new connection, or execute in non-interactive mode, which means nothing executed in a prior command carries over to following commands.

I'm basically new to using streams - there are some methods in the SSH.NET library that appear to open a shell using streams, such that you can assign streams to stdin, stdout, and stderr, but in trying to use them, I can't find good information on how to setup the streams to feed them into the method calls.

1. Do I feed in raw streams?
2. Do I use `MemoryStream` or `TextStream`?

Here's the short definition of the `CreateShell` method in the `SshClient` class in SSH.NET:

```
public Shell CreateShell(Stream input, Stream output, Stream extendedOutput)
{
    return CreateShell(input, output, extendedOutput, string.Empty, 0, 0, 0, 0, null, 1024);
}
```

And the long override version that one uses:

```
public Shell CreateShell(Stream input, Stream output, Stream extendedOutput, string terminalName, uint columns, uint rows, uint width, uint height, IDictionary<TerminalModes, uint> terminalModes, int bufferSize)
{
    EnsureSessionIsOpen();

    return new Shell(Session, input, output, extendedOutput, terminalName, columns, rows, width, height, terminalModes, bufferSize);
}
```

And after setting up the correct streams to attach, how do I read and write to them?  Do I need to setup a `StreamReader` and/or `StreamWriter` to access the stream(s)?  I have already done this in order to read the `StdErr` after using the existing `SshCommand` object with the `.Execute()` method, but I'm not sure how to tie this to the pre-existing streams that I create.

---

### ShellStream Class

Finally, there is another option which seems to make the connection with a single `Stream` object - but I'm unsure if this is just being used for Unit Testing, or if it is viable for "normal" operations:

```
public ShellStream CreateShellStream(string terminalName, uint columns, uint rows, uint width, uint height, int bufferSize, IDictionary<TerminalModes, uint> terminalModeValues)
{
    EnsureSessionIsOpen();

    return ServiceFactory.CreateShellStream(Session, terminalName, columns, rows, width, height, terminalModeValues, bufferSize);
}
```

The `ShellStream : Stream` class does look like a good candidate as well, with overrides to the base `Stream` class for `CanRead`, `CanSeek`, `CanWrite`, `Flush`, `Length`, `Read`, `Write`, etc.

Here is the base definition of the `ShellStream` class, with properties and the constructor:

```
public class ShellStream : Stream
{
    private const string CrLf = "\r\n";

    private readonly ISession _session;
    private readonly Encoding _encoding;
    private readonly int _bufferSize;
    private readonly Queue<byte> _incoming;
    private readonly Queue<byte> _outgoing;
    private IChannelSession _channel;
    private AutoResetEvent _dataReceived = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    private bool _isDisposed;

    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when data was received.
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler<ShellDataEventArgs> DataReceived;

    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when an error occurred.
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler<ExceptionEventArgs> ErrorOccurred;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a value that indicates whether data is available on the <see cref="ShellStream"/> to be read.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// <c>true</c> if data is available to be read; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
    /// </value>
    public bool DataAvailable
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_incoming)
            {
                return _incoming.Count > 0;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the number of bytes that will be written to the internal buffer.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The number of bytes that will be written to the internal buffer.
    /// </value>
    internal int BufferSize
    {
        get { return _bufferSize; }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new <see cref="ShellStream"/> instance.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="session">The SSH session.</param>
    /// <param name="terminalName">The <c>TERM</c> environment variable.</param>
    /// <param name="columns">The terminal width in columns.</param>
    /// <param name="rows">The terminal width in rows.</param>
    /// <param name="width">The terminal height in pixels.</param>
    /// <param name="height">The terminal height in pixels.</param>
    /// <param name="terminalModeValues">The terminal mode values.</param>
    /// <param name="bufferSize">The size of the buffer.</param>
    internal ShellStream(ISession session, string terminalName, uint columns, uint rows, uint width, uint height, IDictionary<TerminalModes, uint> terminalModeValues, int bufferSize)
    {
        _encoding = session.ConnectionInfo.Encoding;
        _session = session;
        _bufferSize = bufferSize;
        _incoming = new Queue<byte>();
        _outgoing = new Queue<byte>();

        _channel = _session.CreateChannelSession();
        _channel.DataReceived += Channel_DataReceived;
        _channel.Closed += Channel_Closed;
        _session.Disconnected += Session_Disconnected;
        _session.ErrorOccured += Session_ErrorOccured;

        _channel.Open();
        _channel.SendPseudoTerminalRequest(terminalName, columns, rows, width, height, terminalModeValues);
        _channel.SendShellRequest();
    }
```

Comment: For those who might find this, looking to understand streams better, see [Can you explain the concept of streams?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/507747/6501141), [C# using streams](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1404303/6501141), and [What is a stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1216380/6501141)

Comment: Marking it duplicate.  I still have questions, but I can post them separately.  Thanks @MartinPrikryl, that's what I needed to get started.

Comment: Good. What about [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46847304/850848)? Do you need anything more?

Comment: I'll try to work through using PipeStream, and see how things go.  I guess I was wondering if the ShellStream class was newer or what it's purpose is, if PipeStream will work (and the other answer explains adequately why it works).